# Access dict keys and list elements by same index to loop over and assign values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have more than 15 dataframes and one list. Given the sample below

```
unit_list = ['%','umol/l','mmol/l','mmol/l','g/dL','mmol/l','umol/l','','mg/mmol','mg/L','','mg/mmol','g/L'
        'g/day','','mg/L','','mg/day','','mmol/l','','cells/uL','','','cells/uL']

#TWO DATAFRAME for sample

dataframesdict[hbA1c] = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,2,3],'Date': ['2009-01-05 00:00:00','2009-01-05 00:00:00','2013-01-31 00:00:00'],'Value': [9.6,9.6,10]})
dataframesdict[Creatinine]   = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,2,3],'Date': ['2119-01-05 00:00:00','2129-01-05 00:00:00','2113-01-31 00:00:00'],'Value': [19.6,29.6,210]})
```

What I would like to do is create a new column called `unit` in each dataframe present under the `dataframesdict` and fill the value from `unit_list`

I have got the `unit_list` ordered, so its like 0th element from `unit_list` should be filled in as value for `unit` column under 0th key (0th dataframe) in `dataframesdict`

Similarly `dataframesdict[1]['unit] = unit_list[1]`

I tried the below but it doesn't work due to the use of Index as key.

```
for i in range(len(key_list)):
    dataFramesDict[i]['unit'] = unit_list[i]
```

How can I make use of index to access and assign values at the same time? Below screenshot shows the expected output. Hba1c is the first index item in dict, so the corresponding first index item from unit_list is filled in as value in 'unit' column of the dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Python 3.7.1 (it retains dict order) and the below answer works.However I welcome any better and efficient answer and looking forward to it

```
for i in range(len(key_list)):
    a = list(dataFramesDict)[i]
    dataFramesDict[a]['unit'] = unit_list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, unless you are on python 3.6=>, `dict` will **not** guarantee you the order. In order words, `hdA1c` will not always be the first key.

If you were to maintain the order, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

As for the actual problem, `enumerate` would do the job:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(dataframesdict.items()):
    v['unit'] = unit_list[i]

print(dataframesdict['hbA1c'])
```

Output:

```
                  Date  Value  person_id unit
0  2009-01-05 00:00:00    9.6          1    %
1  2009-01-05 00:00:00    9.6          2    %
2  2013-01-31 00:00:00   10.0          3    %
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.1. So will that retain the dict order?

Comment: @ALVES yes it should. I wasn't sure because the tag included `python-2.7` :P

Comment: Your answer is better as it applies across all version of Python. Will mark as a silution after the time limit is over

Comment: Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285680/dont-drop-all-nas-during-stack-operation-in-python